# Sum of 5's and 7's

Tags: problem-solving, integers

So I've been given the following problem:

How many positive integers are there that can not be written as a sum of 5's and 7's? For example, 4 is one of those integers, but 19 is not because 19 = 5 + 7 + 7. How to solve this?

Comment: What efforts have you made?

Comment: See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coin_problem

Comment: I tested a bunch of numbers, and found 11 numbers. My thought was that when I get above a certain point, all numbers can be written as a sum of 5's and 7's, so I stopped at around 30. Now I'm looking for a more mathematical way of solving it

Comment: Thanks for the link!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hints:

(1) Start at the beginning: Can you get $1$, $2$,...

(2) If you can write a number $n$ as a sum of $5$s and $7$s, you can write $n+5$ as a sum of $5$s and $7$s.

(3) If you ever achieve five consecutive numbers  that you can write as a sum of $5$s and $7$s, what will hint (2) allow you to conclude?

Comment: Ah I see how it is. If I achieve five consecutive numbers, that means all numbers larger than the first of those five can be written as a such sum! Clever. Thank you for your answer

Answer (score 0):

It is easy enough to conclude that a such positive integer $n$ must be of the form $$n=5a+7b+c$$ where $a,b$ are non-negative integers and $c$ are positive integers with $c\lt 35$, coprime with $35$ and such that $c$ is not solution of $5a+7b=c$.

There are $\phi(35)=(5-1)(7-1)=24$ positive integers coprimes with $35$ and less than it:$$1,2,3,4,6,8,9,11,12,13,16,17,18,19,22,23,24,26,27,29,31,32,33,34$$ of which the following twelve $$12,17,19,22,24,26,27,29,31,32,33,34$$ are solution of  $5a+7b=c$ (this has been easily found taking sums among $5,10,15,20,25,30$ and $7,14,21,28$).

Consequently the asked numbers are given by all the positive integers of the form
$$\color{red}{5a+7b=c\text{ where } c=1,2,3,4,6,8,9,11,13,16,18,23}$$

Comment: There is an evident typo in the red line: it is $5a+7b+c$ instead of $5a+7b=c$ I don't edit and it is enough this comment.